# Stopping calls to Ubuntu Music Search API

Tags: 12.04, music

How can I stop my Ubuntu machine from making calls to the Ubuntu Music Search API (http://alkes.canonical.com/)?

Comment: What do you mean by your Ubuntu server? The server version of Ubuntu doesn't have any of the GUI components of desktop installed by default, so doesn't make any calls to the music search API. Please be more specific about what you are doing.

Comment: sorry i meant ubuntu machine. not a server

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the Ubuntu Music Search API service

If all else fails, simply divert the hostname to a different IP. The calls won't stop but the external traffic will as it should 404 immediately.

Do this by editing your `/etc/hosts` file (as root) and adding `X.X.X.X example.com`

For example, you may add `127.0.0.1 alkes.canonical.com`.

Here's a one-liner command to do the task:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 alkes.canonical.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping for a better solution, where I can just turn of the service that is making these calls.....